# Conditionally highlight value that is seperated from another but within the same cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table of data where every cell is in the form `0.123(0.345)` (numbers could be anything below 1). Is there any way to highlight the cell if numbers in parentheses are less than 0.01 WITHOUT splitting the values into separate cells?

examples:

```
0.1(0.0008)   HIGHLIGHTED
0.999(0.673)   not highlighted
```

Answer (score 1):

If your values are in column A, try selecting the column and click Format > Conditional formatting > Custom formula is

`=ABS(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\(0\.\d*\)")))<0.01`

Comment: That looks like it should work, but it didnt highlight any values for me

Comment: Here is an sheet using your example values: https://goo.gl/En9gH8 Can you see any differences compared to your own file?